# View is not returned by Controller on production server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hello I have created a website with the Laravel 4 framework and somehow since yesterday there is a problem with 1 view on the production server.

When the controller returns a view like

```
return View::make('site/reservation/vehicle')
```

it actually stays on the same page as before and does not redirect me to vehicle page. When I replace the view with a simple String I do get the value of the string though.. the whole method looks like this

```
public function getDates() {

    $value = Session::get('reserveringen');

    return View::make('site/reservation/vehicle')
    ->with('gegevens', $value)
    ->with('vehicles', $this->vehicles->getVehicleByDate($value['pickupsub'], $value['returnsub']));

}
```

The same code works like a charm on the dev server. Is there anything that could cause this problem ?

Comment: Can you go somewhere except to the home page (`/`) ? If not, you have to check that mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Yes. I can go to other pages :) I am going to try and change the virtual host since u told me this I remember I made some changes..

Comment: Make sure your webserver is able to read the file `app/views/site/reservation/vehicle.blade.php`.

Comment: I have copied and moved a old version of the vhost file and reloaded the server it works now. Gonna chek if i can find the problem thanks for the help @AlexandreButynski